# POI - replacing HSSFWorkbook.setRepeatingRowsAndColumns(0, 0, totalReportColumns, 0, 4) to XSSFWorkbook

Tags: apache-poi

I am using apache POI latest version. I am trying to convert existing code which was written using HSSFWorkbook. I found it is using HSSFWorkbook.setRepeatingRowsAndColumns(0, 0, totalReportColumns, 0, 4)
that I need to convert. Not knowing much of the logic, I am not sure how to use the new API to convert above statement. Could some one help converting this to XSSFWorkbook equivalent? Thanks!

Comment: If you could provide a [example] (surrounding code) it would help to have the context for desired conversion. Which POI version do you use?

Comment: Trying to convert existing code that uses HSSF to XSSF workbook. I found one line at the end as the method as "HSSFWorkbook.setRepeatingRowsAndColumns(0, 0, totalReportColumns, 0, 4)" - Wondering how can I conevrt this to XSSF.